# Automatic analysis on multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

As per the following code, using panda, I am doing some analysis on one of the columns (**HR**):

```
aa = New_Data['index'].tolist()
aa = [0] + aa
avg = []
for i in range(1,len(aa)):
   ** val = raw_data.loc[(raw_data['index'] >= aa[i-1]) & (raw_data['index'] <= aa[i])['HR'].diff().mean()
    avg.append(val)
New_Data['slope'] = avg
```

AT the end of the day, it will add a new column to the data ('Slope')
That is fine and is working. The problem is that I want to redo the line (which is specified by **) for every other columns (not just HR) as well. in Other words,:

```
** val = raw_data.loc[(raw_data['index'] >= aa[i-1]) & (raw_data['index'] <= aa[i])['**another column**'].diff().mean()

avg.append(val)
New_Data['slope'] = avg
```

Is there any way to do it automatically? I have around 100 columns so doing manually is not enticing. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure on the pure pandas way but you could just write in a external loop -

```
aa = New_Data['index'].tolist()
aa = [0] + aa
avg = []
for col in df.columns:
    for i in range(1,len(aa)):
       ** val = raw_data.loc[(raw_data['index'] >= aa[i-1]) & (raw_data['index'] <= aa[i])[col].diff().mean()
    avg.append(val)
New_Data['slope'] = avg
```

In the line

```
for col in df.columns
```

you can modify to only use columns you need.

Comment: Great! Is there any way to make the name ,slope, automatic as well? I mean since multiple columns are added, I want their name to be different.

Comment: This is still a `for` loop. So you can modify it to work on individual column basics. Eg. ```for col in df.columns : df['new_'+col] = df[col] + 1 ```